# apache calcite, querying without using the jdbc api

Tags: apache-calcite

I would like to use the apache calcite api raw without using jdbc connections. I can use the jdbc api just fine but I am getting null ptr exceptions when trying to use the api. What I did so far is:

```
package calcite.examples

import java.util.Properties

import calcite.demo.DemoSchema
import org.apache.calcite.DataContext
import org.apache.calcite.config.CalciteConnectionConfigImpl
import org.apache.calcite.jdbc.CalcitePrepare.Query
import org.apache.calcite.jdbc.{CalcitePrepare, CalciteSchema, JavaTypeFactoryImpl}
import org.apache.calcite.prepare.CalcitePrepareImpl

import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

object TryIt extends App
{
    val ctx = new AdapterContext
    val sql = Query.of[Any]("SELECT * FROM dep")
    //  assert(sql.rel != null)

    val elementType = classOf[Array[Object]]
    val prepared = new CalcitePrepareImpl().prepareSql(ctx, sql, elementType, -1)
    val enumerable = prepared.enumerable(new MyDataContext)
}

class AdapterContext extends CalcitePrepare.Context
{
    private val properties = new Properties
    private val rootSchema = CalciteSchema.createRootSchema(true)
    rootSchema.add("default", new DemoSchema)

    // default schema names
    override def getDefaultSchemaPath = List("default").asJava

    override def spark() = {
        val enable = config.spark
        CalcitePrepare.Dummy.getSparkHandler(enable)
    }

    override val config = new CalciteConnectionConfigImpl(properties)

    override val getTypeFactory = new JavaTypeFactoryImpl

    override def getRootSchema = rootSchema

    override def getDataContext = new MyDataContext
}

class MyDataContext extends DataContext
{
    override def get(name: String) = {
        println(s"MyDataContext name=$name")
        null
    }

    override def getTypeFactory = ???

    override def getQueryProvider = ???

    override def getRootSchema = ???
}
```

But when I run this I get

MyDataContext name=v0stashed

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.calcite.interpreter.Interpreter.<init>(Interpreter.java:71)
at Baz.bind(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.calcite.jdbc.CalcitePrepare$CalciteSignature.enumerable(CalcitePrepare.java:327)
at calcite.examples.TryIt$.delayedEndpoint$calcite$examples$TryIt$1(TryIt.scala:26)
at calcite.examples.TryIt$delayedInit$body.apply(TryIt.scala:18)
at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)
at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:35)
at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:76)
at calcite.examples.TryIt$.main(TryIt.scala:18)
at calcite.examples.TryIt.main(TryIt.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

Notice that it tries to get v0stashed from the context, which I don't know what it should be. The only CalcitePrepare.Context impl I see is one that uses a CalciteConnection, which I am trying to avoid using. Also I took snippets of code from the calcite docs but it was out of date with calcite 1.7

Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

There's some crazy stuff going on here apparently.  You need to pass `internalParameters` that you get out of the prepare call into your DataContext, and look them up in `get`.  Apparently Calcite uses this to pass the query object around.  You probably want to implement the other DataContext keys (current time, etc) as well.

```
final class MyDataContext(rootSchema: SchemaPlus, map: util.Map[String, Object])
        extends DataContext {
    override def get(name: String): AnyRef = map.get(name)

...
}
```

```
// ctx is your AdapterContext from above
val prepared = new CalcitePrepareImpl().prepareSql(ctx, query, classOf[Array[Object]], -1)
val dataContext = new DerpDataContext(
  ctx.getRootSchema.plus(),
  prepared.internalParameters
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should almost work, I have the same thing with some stuff changed using the `JdbcSchema`.  My hunch is you're trying to use a spark schema, and just judging by the version numbers in Calcite, I don't think it's maintained very well.  Try a simpler schema, like the reflective HR one, or the JDBC schema and it should work, with some small changes to what you have.